# How does the angle key from arrows.meta TikZ library work?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows, metapost

The title says it all. How does `angle=<angle>:<first dimen> <second dimen>` works. More exactly, what do the first length and the second length mean?

```
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\tikzset{mparr/.tip={Triangle[round,angle=45:4bp 0bp]}}
```

I was trying to copy the style from MetaPost, which I like. So the main idea is to find the correct values for `<first dimen>` and `<second dimen>` so it resembles the arrows from MetaPost.

---

In any case, if you have any suggestions to imitate the style of MetaPost, they are welcome. (The `bend` option from `bending` library doesn't convince me, the result is always less beautiful than MetaPost arrows.)

Here's an example with a MetaPost figure. Those weird `\relax`es are there because I played with `\rlap` and `\llap` to see if the figures had similar results when playing with the values.

```
%!TEX TS-program = lualatex

\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tikz,luamplib,tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,bending,decorations.markings}

\tikzset{mparr/.tip={Triangle[round,angle=45:5bp]}} % 5bp being 4bp+2\pgflinewidth
\tikzset{mpstyle/.style={line width=.5bp,line join=round,line cap=round,>=mparr,every node/.append style={inner sep=2bp}}}

\begin{document}

\indent\relax{\begin{tikzpicture}[mpstyle]
  \draw[<->] (2,0) -- (0,0) -- (0,2);
  \draw[->] (0,0) .. controls (1,0) and (1,2) .. (2,2);
\end{tikzpicture}}%
\relax{\begin{mplibcode}
  %ahlength := 4bp;
  %ahangle := 45;
  beginfig(1);
    drawdblarrow (2cm,0) -- (0,0) -- (0,2cm);
    drawarrow (0,0) .. controls (1cm,0) and (1cm,2cm) .. (2cm,2cm)
      %withpen pencircle scaled 10bp
      ;
  endfig;
\end{mplibcode}}

\end{document}
```

There are a few things that I don't completely understand: I can't draw the arrows in TikZ with any line width, it seems fixed, the `round` option doesn't take in account if the line width is , e.g., `11cm`; if I change the `ahangle := 20` then the similarity is lost even if I do `angle=20:5bp`, I don't really know how it works.

P.S.: I know there are nice answers to the question in the title, but I stated in the question that my goal was to copy the arrows (and style in general) from MetaPost, so I will wait a little bit longer in case someone comes with a nice solution.

Answer (score 9):

In fact, `angle` accepts four arguments: (notice the spaces)

> ```
> angle=⟨angle⟩:⟨dimension⟩␣⟨line width factor⟩␣⟨outer factor⟩
> ```

These arguments are introduced for only one reason: **flexibility**.

[image]

### (1 2 3)

First of all we would like to assign the shape and the size of an arrow tip directly. This leads to a simple convention:

> ```
> angle=⟨angle⟩:⟨dimension⟩
> ```

which fails to be an arrow if lines are too thick. Especially in case (3), the line is as big the tip.

```
\draw[line width= 2pt,arrows={-Triangle[lw0r,angle=60:10pt   ]}]( 1,0)--+(0,1)node{ 1};
\draw[line width= 5pt,arrows={-Triangle[lw0r,angle=60:10pt   ]}]( 2,0)--+(0,1)node{ 2};
\draw[line width=10pt,arrows={-Triangle[lw0r,angle=60:10pt   ]}]( 3,0)--+(0,1)node{ 3};
```

### (4 5 6)

So we then have a more elaborated protocol:

> ```
> angle=⟨angle⟩:⟨dimension⟩␣⟨line width factor⟩
> ```

Such that in these cases, tips are twice as big as the lines are.

```
\draw[line width= 2pt,arrows={-Triangle[lw0r,angle=60 :0pt  2]}]( 4,0)--+(0,1)node{ 4};
\draw[line width= 5pt,arrows={-Triangle[lw0r,angle=60 :0pt  2]}]( 5,0)--+(0,1)node{ 5};
\draw[line width=10pt,arrows={-Triangle[lw0r,angle=60 :0pt  2]}]( 6,0)--+(0,1)node{ 6};
```

### (7 8 9)

You can also, illustrated below, set the size of tips to be larger than that of the lines by exactly `5pt`.

```
\draw[line width= 2pt,arrows={-Triangle[lw0r,angle=60 :5pt  1]}]( 7,0)--+(0,1)node{ 7};
\draw[line width= 5pt,arrows={-Triangle[lw0r,angle=60 :5pt  1]}]( 8,0)--+(0,1)node{ 8};
\draw[line width=10pt,arrows={-Triangle[lw0r,angle=60 :5pt  1]}]( 9,0)--+(0,1)node{ 9};
```

### Even more complicated

Things become insane once the lines become `double`d.

[image]

### (4 5 6 7 8 9)

The first six arrows look OK: The tip size is a linear function in line width.

```
\draw[line width= 2pt,arrows={-Triangle[lw0r,angle=60 :0pt  2  ]}]( 4,0)--+(0,3)node{ 4};
\draw[line width= 5pt,arrows={-Triangle[lw0r,angle=60 :0pt  2  ]}]( 5,0)--+(0,3)node{ 5};
\draw[line width=10pt,arrows={-Triangle[lw0r,angle=60 :0pt  2  ]}]( 6,0)--+(0,3)node{ 6};
\draw[line width= 2pt,arrows={-Triangle[lw0r,angle=60 :5pt  1  ]}]( 7,0)--+(0,3)node{ 7};
\draw[line width= 5pt,arrows={-Triangle[lw0r,angle=60 :5pt  1  ]}]( 8,0)--+(0,3)node{ 8};
\draw[line width=10pt,arrows={-Triangle[lw0r,angle=60 :5pt  1  ]}]( 9,0)--+(0,3)node{ 9};
```

### (10 11 12)

And then a problem arise: can the tip size grows with respect to the *outer* line width? So the forth argument involves.

```
\draw[line width= 2pt,arrows={-Triangle[lw0r,angle=60 :0pt  1 1]}](10,0)--+(0,3)node{10};
\draw[line width= 5pt,arrows={-Triangle[lw0r,angle=60 :0pt  1 1]}](11,0)--+(0,3)node{11};
\draw[line width=10pt,arrows={-Triangle[lw0r,angle=60 :0pt  1 1]}](12,0)--+(0,3)node{12};
```

By default, `outer factor`, the forth argument, is set to be `0`. Hence the *weighted* line width, the dimension to be multiplied by the `line width factor`, is equal to the *total* line width. That is, the sum of the widths of the black-white-black lines. Or equally *inner* + 2·*outer*.

On the other hand if `outer factor` is `1`, the *weighted* line width is the *outer* line width, i.e. the width of the black line. For any other values, the *weighted* line width will be the linear interpolation of the *total* and *outer* line widths.

### (13 14 15)

So... Can the tip size grows with respect to the *inner* line width? The answer require some math:

```
\draw[line width= 2pt,arrows={-Triangle[lw0r,angle=60 :0pt -1 2]}](13,0)--+(0,3)node{13};
\draw[line width= 5pt,arrows={-Triangle[lw0r,angle=60 :0pt -1 2]}](14,0)--+(0,3)node{14};
\draw[line width=10pt,arrows={-Triangle[lw0r,angle=60 :0pt -1 2]}](15,0)--+(0,3)node{15};
```

### Full code and side marks

- In the definition of `lw0r`, the `line width=0` aims to cancel the counter path of tips.

  - Strangely `draw=none` gives the `do not know the key 'draw'` error.
- If you are good at math, you will found that we cannot set the *weighted* line width to be *inner* + *outer*.
- For later referencing, the main calculation is done by `\pgfarrowslinewidthdependent` in `pgfcorearrows.code.tex`.

> tip length = size·cos(angle/2)
>   tip width = size·2·sin(angle/2)
>   size = ⟨dimension⟩ + ⟨line width factor⟩·*weighted*
>   *weighted* = ⟨outer factor⟩·*outer* + (1-⟨outer factor⟩)·*total*
>   *weighted* = (2-⟨outer factor⟩)·*outer* + (1-⟨outer factor⟩)·*inner*

- In the same file there is also a `\pgfarrowslengthdependent` taking three arguments : `⟨dimension⟩`, `⟨length factor⟩`, `⟨line width factor⟩`.

> tip width = ⟨dimension⟩ + ⟨length factor⟩·tip length + ⟨line width factor⟩·line width

- No more `dependent`-like macros as far as I know.

Code:

```
\documentclass[border=9,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{/pgf/arrow keys/lw0r/.style={line width=0,red}}

\begin{tikzpicture}[nodes=above]
    \draw[line width= 2pt,arrows={-Triangle[lw0r,angle=60:10pt   ]}]( 1,0)--+(0,1)node{ 1};
    \draw[line width= 5pt,arrows={-Triangle[lw0r,angle=60:10pt   ]}]( 2,0)--+(0,1)node{ 2};
    \draw[line width=10pt,arrows={-Triangle[lw0r,angle=60:10pt   ]}]( 3,0)--+(0,1)node{ 3};
    \draw[line width= 2pt,arrows={-Triangle[lw0r,angle=60 :0pt  2]}]( 4,0)--+(0,1)node{ 4};
    \draw[line width= 5pt,arrows={-Triangle[lw0r,angle=60 :0pt  2]}]( 5,0)--+(0,1)node{ 5};
    \draw[line width=10pt,arrows={-Triangle[lw0r,angle=60 :0pt  2]}]( 6,0)--+(0,1)node{ 6};
    \draw[line width= 2pt,arrows={-Triangle[lw0r,angle=60 :5pt  1]}]( 7,0)--+(0,1)node{ 7};
    \draw[line width= 5pt,arrows={-Triangle[lw0r,angle=60 :5pt  1]}]( 8,0)--+(0,1)node{ 8};
    \draw[line width=10pt,arrows={-Triangle[lw0r,angle=60 :5pt  1]}]( 9,0)--+(0,1)node{ 9};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[nodes=above,every path/.style=double,double distance=10pt]
    \draw[line width= 2pt,arrows={-Triangle[lw0r,angle=60 :0pt  2  ]}]( 4,0)--+(0,3)node{ 4};
    \draw[line width= 5pt,arrows={-Triangle[lw0r,angle=60 :0pt  2  ]}]( 5,0)--+(0,3)node{ 5};
    \draw[line width=10pt,arrows={-Triangle[lw0r,angle=60 :0pt  2  ]}]( 6,0)--+(0,3)node{ 6};
    \draw[line width= 2pt,arrows={-Triangle[lw0r,angle=60 :5pt  1  ]}]( 7,0)--+(0,3)node{ 7};
    \draw[line width= 5pt,arrows={-Triangle[lw0r,angle=60 :5pt  1  ]}]( 8,0)--+(0,3)node{ 8};
    \draw[line width=10pt,arrows={-Triangle[lw0r,angle=60 :5pt  1  ]}]( 9,0)--+(0,3)node{ 9};
    \draw[line width= 2pt,arrows={-Triangle[lw0r,angle=60 :0pt  1 1]}](10,0)--+(0,3)node{10};
    \draw[line width= 5pt,arrows={-Triangle[lw0r,angle=60 :0pt  1 1]}](11,0)--+(0,3)node{11};
    \draw[line width=10pt,arrows={-Triangle[lw0r,angle=60 :0pt  1 1]}](12,0)--+(0,3)node{12};
    \draw[line width= 2pt,arrows={-Triangle[lw0r,angle=60 :0pt -1 2]}](13,0)--+(0,3)node{13};
    \draw[line width= 5pt,arrows={-Triangle[lw0r,angle=60 :0pt -1 2]}](14,0)--+(0,3)node{14};
    \draw[line width=10pt,arrows={-Triangle[lw0r,angle=60 :0pt -1 2]}](15,0)--+(0,3)node{15};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That's detailed. One thing I can't get right is that (it seems that) the arrows from MetaPost are `4bp + 2·⟨linewidth⟩` and, in the code I can't use it. Any way I could define the arrow with `angle=45:4bp+2\pgflinewidth,`? By the way, you have an extra `:` after (4 5 6) in the code `angle=⟨angle⟩:⟨dimension⟩:␣⟨line width factor⟩`.

Comment: @Manuel As you want `45` degrees, there is a sin(22.5) factor somewhere. You probably have to figure it out yourself since I know nothing about MetaPost. And do not forget the line width of the tip itself.

Comment: Mmm… I still don't know how it works. I expected the Triangle to be drawn “theoretically” and then `\drawfill`ed. So I expected the arrow to grow when using `ultra thick` and that's not the case.

Comment: Forget `double`d lines, you may try `angle=45:4bp 2`, which is the official version of `angle=45:4bp+2\pgflinewidth`. But as I just said, even the latter may not be what you want. (Consider to give a MetaPost MWE?)

Answer (score 4):

From [pgfmanual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pgf), page 186

[image]

And a little example

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,bending}

\tikzset{mparr/.tip={Triangle[round,angle=45:4bp]}}
\tikzset{mpstyle/.style={line width=.5bp,line join=round,line cap=round,>=mparr}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[mpstyle]
  \draw[->] (0,0) .. controls (1,0) and (1,2) .. (2,2) ;
  \draw[<->] (2,0) -- (0,0) -- (0,2);
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[mparr/.tip={Triangle[round,angle=45:4bp 4]},
            mpstyle, xshift=3cm]
  \draw[->] (0,0) .. controls (1,0) and (1,2) .. (2,2) ;
  \draw[<->] (2,0) -- (0,0) -- (0,2);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I missed this one, and I found no reference to it in the `arrows.meta` section.