# Dealing with overlapping vectors tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, tkz-euclide

The following produces undesirable output because the "tails" of the vectors are overlapping and hard to see. Is there a way to automate something better by having all vectors draw only 95% of their distance?

Is there an even a better solution than the one I prescribed?

Additionally, how can one swap up the arrowhead `->` for a closed arrow `-|>`?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
%\tkzInit[xmin=-3,xmax=7,ymin=-6,ymax=5] \tkzGrid
\tkzInit

\tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
\tkzDefPoint(4,0){B}
\tkzDefPoint(5,-3){C}
\tkzDefPoint(1,-3){D}

\draw[thick,->] (A) -- (B) node[above] {$B$};
\draw[thick,<-] (B) -- (C) node[below] {$C$};
\draw[thick,<-] (C) -- (D) node[below] {$D$};
\draw[thick,->] (D) -- (A) node[above] {$A$};

\tkzDefMidPoint(B,D) \tkzGetPoint{E}
\draw[thick,->] (D) -- (E) node[above] {$E$};
\draw[thick,->] (C) -- (E);
\draw[thick,->] (E) -- (A);
\draw[thick,->] (E) -- (B);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: To avoid this problem, one of my colleague (math teacher) simply puts the arrow at the middle of the path :-)

Comment: Wouldn't that system become confusing if, say, I had to draw a vector from A halfway to B?

Comment: No, if you only place only the arrow tip itself in the middle of the segment. Without drawing another segment, only the tip. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/234689/how-to-mark-a-segment-with-an-arrow-in-tkz-euclid-with-the-tkzmarksegment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A workaround would be to chose full arrow tips, and to reduce the angle of these tips while increasing their length accordingly. Since I don't know much about `tikz` and less about its arrows, here is an example with MetaPost, in which I've changed the default values of the relevant parameters `ahlength` and `ahangle` to suit the figure.

Included in a LuaLaTeX program for typesetting convenience:

```
\documentclass[border=2bp]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
  \mplibsetformat{metafun}
  \mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{document}
\begin{mplibcode}
  numeric u; u = 1.5cm;
  pair A, B, C, D, E; 
  A = origin; B = (4u, 0); C = u*(5, -3); D = u*(1, -3);
  E = .5[B, D] = .5[A, C];
  beginfig(1);
    ahangle := 22.5; % default 45°
    ahlength := 8bp; % default 4 bp
    drawarrow A -- B;
    drawarrow B -- C;
    drawarrow C -- D;
    drawarrow D -- A;
    drawarrow D -- E;
    drawarrow C -- E;
    drawarrow E -- A;
    drawarrow E -- B;
    freelabeloffset := 1.5bp;
    for str = "A", "B", "C", "D":
      freelabel("$" & str & "$", scantokens str, E);
    endfor
    label.top("$E$", E);
  endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

Before the changes to `ahlength` and `ahangle`:

[image]

After the changes:

[image]

Comment: I've just noticed that there is currently a post whose author seeks to recreate with `tikz` the same kind of arrows than with MetaPost: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/235283/how-does-the-angle-key-from-arrows-meta-tikz-library-work. It can serve as  a complement to my answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `shorten` per line basis. There is no global (automatic solution) change possible since the directions are different here. To swap arrow head from `->` to `-|>`, use `\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}` and do `-|>`..

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
%\tkzInit[xmin=-3,xmax=7,ymin=-6,ymax=5] \tkzGrid
\tkzInit

\tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
\tkzDefPoint(4,0){B}
\tkzDefPoint(5,-3){C}
\tkzDefPoint(1,-3){D}

\draw[thick,->,shorten >=.5mm] (A) -- (B) node[above] {$B$};
\draw[thick,<-,shorten <=.5mm] (B) -- (C) node[below] {$C$};
\draw[thick,<-,shorten <=.5mm] (C) -- (D) node[below] {$D$};
\draw[thick,->,shorten >=.5mm] (D) -- (A) node[above] {$A$};

\tkzDefMidPoint(B,D) \tkzGetPoint{E}
\draw[thick,->,shorten >=.5mm] (D) -- (E) node[above] {$E$};
\draw[thick,->,shorten >=.5mm] (C) -- (E);
\draw[thick,->,shorten >=.7mm] (E) -- (A);
\draw[thick,->,shorten >=.5mm] (E) -- (B);

%% arrow head

\draw[thick,-|>] (C) -- +(2cm,0);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Adjust `.5mm` as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

Global options are not a problem actually. You just define a style and change the direction of the arrows in the `\draw` command, i.e. you always say "draw an arrow from x to y" and y is the where the arrow points.

Also for closed arrow tips, you should look at the arrows library of tikz. A simple one is `-stealth`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
    scale=1.5,
    ar/.style={thick, -stealth, shorten >=.5mm}]
  \tkzInit

  \tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
  \tkzDefPoint(4,0){B}
  \tkzDefPoint(5,-3){C}
  \tkzDefPoint(1,-3){D}

  \draw[ar] (A) -- (B) node[above] {$B$};
  \draw[ar] (C) -- (B) node[below] {$C$};
  \draw[ar] (D) -- (C) node[below] {$D$};
  \draw[ar] (D) -- (A) node[above] {$A$};

  \tkzDefMidPoint(B,D) \tkzGetPoint{E}
  \draw[ar] (D) -- (E) node[above] {$E$};
  \draw[ar] (C) -- (E);
  \draw[ar] (E) -- (A);
  \draw[ar] (E) -- (B);

  %% arrow head

  \draw[thick,-|>] (C) -- +(2cm,0);

 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```